# How to decompress lzma2 (.xz) and zstd (.zst) files into a folder using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, lzma, zstandard

I have been working for a long time with `.bz2` files. To unpack/decompress `.bz2` files into a specific folder I have been using the following function:

```
destination_folder = 'unpacked/'
def decompress_bz2_to_folder(input_file):
    unpackedfile = bz2.BZ2File(input_file)
    data = unpackedfile.read()
    open(destination_folder, 'wb').write(data)
```

Recently I obtained a list of files with the `.xz` (not `.tar.xz`) and `.zst` extensions. My poor research skills told me that the former is `lzma2` compression and the latter is `Zstandard`.

However, I couldn't find of an easy way to unpack the contents of these archives into a folder (like I do with the `.bz2` files).

How can I:

1. Unpack the contents of an `.xz` (`lzma2`) file into a folder using
   Python 3?
2. Unpack the contents of a `.zst` (`Zstandard`) file into a folder using Python 3?

**Important Note:** I'm unpacking [very large files](https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/), so it would be great if the solution takes into consideration any potential ***Memory Errors***.

Comment: The `zstd` cli can decompress both `.xz` and `.zst` files, if built with appropriate options. This can be checked with `zstd -vV`. Example : `zstd -vV`, `*** zstd command line interface 64-bits v1.3.2, by Yann Collet ***`, `*** supports: zstd, zstd legacy v0.4+, gzip, lz4, lzma, xz`

Comment: @Cyan That's good to know. How can it be done in Python 3 though? :)

Comment: By invoking the CLI as an external command line utility ?

If you have to use tighter integration instead, you may be interested in a [python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The LZMA data can be decompressed using the [`lzma` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html), simply open the file with that module, then use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to efficiently copy the decompressed data to an output file without running into memory issues:

```
import lzma
import pathlib
import shutil

def decompress_lzma_to_folder(input_file):
    input_file = pathlib.Path(input_file)
    with lzma.open(input_file) as compressed:
        output_path = pathlib.Path(destination_dir) / input_file.stem
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as destination:
            shutil.copyfileobj(compressed, destination)
```

The Python standard library doesn't have any support for Zstandard compression yet, you can use either the [`zstandard`](https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/) (by IndyGreg from Mozilla and the Mercurial project) or [`zstd`](https://pypi.org/project/zstd/); the latter is perhaps too basic for your needs, while `zstandard` offers a streaming API specifically suited for reading files.

I'm using the `zstandard` library here to benefit from the copying API it implements, which lets you decompress and copy at the same time, similar to how `shutil.copyfileobj()` works:

```
import zstandard
import pathlib

def decompress_zstandard_to_folder(input_file):
    input_file = pathlib.Path(input_file)
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as compressed:
        decomp = zstandard.ZstdDecompressor()
        output_path = pathlib.Path(destination_dir) / input_file.stem
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as destination:
            decomp.copy_stream(compressed, destination)
```